# navsat robot_localization

Tags: ros, gps, navsat-transform-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Navasat_transform_node have a question about when the node receives a position becomes GPS latitude and longitude, UTM this format is x, and an identifier of area and band, for example Spain 29T, 30T and 31T, what happens when we change area or band ? X and Y incrise continue or start again?

Edit1:
I have other problem, i download the last version for indigo and the ekf not publish the tf between base_link and odom like the other versions. Whats happen?
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214630/navsat-robot_localization/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-28**:
Your IMU message appears to have 0 time stamps. That won't work. Fix that, and if your issue isn't resolved, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do believe that situation may cause trouble, so I've added an [issue](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/222) to the tracker and will update this answer when the fix is complete. While I can generate a made-up bag file with the right GPS coordinates to test this situation, if you happen to have one that you can share, I'd like to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-07-28**:
ok! I will generate a rosbag with this situation.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-07-28**:
That will be very helpful, thank you.